# Media Player error in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

i have a RecyclerView that displays a list of songs and i have successfully implemented on click listener with it and verified it with logs. Now i want to play the song upon click event. When i first click on a item the songs starts to play but if i then tap on any other item the app simply crashes

Here is my RecyclerViewClickListener

```
SongAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter(getContext(), songsList, new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You clicked on Ssong "+songsList.get(position).getSongName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            songPath = songsList.get(position).getUrl();
            Log.v("Song Path", songPath);
            if(mp.isPlaying())
                releaseMediaResources();
            playSong();
        }
    });
recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
```

Here is my playSong method

```
private void playSong () {
        if(!songPath.equals("")) {
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Home Fragment", "Error setting song Url", e);
            }
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And here is my releaseMediaResources

```
private void releaseMediaResources() {
    mp.stop();
    mp.reset();
    mp.release();
}
```

These are the errors

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
    at com.ashutosh.prototype4.HomeFragment.playSong(HomeFragment.java:159)
    at com.ashutosh.prototype4.HomeFragment.releaseMediaResources(HomeFragment.java:192)
    at com.ashutosh.prototype4.HomeFragment.access$100(HomeFragment.java:31)
    at com.ashutosh.prototype4.HomeFragment$2.onClick(HomeFragment.java:94)
    at com.ashutosh.prototype4.SongAdapter$1.onClick(SongAdapter.java:50)
```

According to me the main problem lies in setting up the media player because when i display only toast messages there's no issues at all but as soon as i implement media player to on click method the crash occurs

Comment: create singleton class of media player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will create every time the new MediaPlayer, but of course try to check, if there is not already existing instance for instance:

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private void playSong(String filePath) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.parse(filePath));
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(DEFAULT_VOLUME_MUSIC, DEFAULT_VOLUME_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        }
    });
}
```